# Updating with new nodes in an array - Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So when you `set()` nodes in the Firebas database the structure automatically  looks like this:

```
0
    a: info
    b: info
1
    a: info
    b: info
```

and so on. Now, if I'd like to continue the array with node 2, how do i go about? I've been using this string to set/create nodes:

```
database.ref("root/issues/" + titleName).set(issues);
```

Been trying some other command words like `push()` and `update()` with and without `child()` but end up with either over writing everything or that stupid, dumb unique key, like this:

```
0
    a: info
    b: info

1
    a: info
    b: info

-uubaPUUba89va08U(or whatever)
    0
        a: info
        b: info
    1
        a: info
        b: info
```

Using Javascript.

Comment: can you show your full code of adding 0 and 1 nodes?

Comment: Well, the one line of code shown in my question is what sets it in the database. Not sure how I can elaborate on that, or am I misunderstanding your comment? @PeterHaddad

Comment: what is `issues` equal to? Do you have to add 0 and 1? Can't you use this `uubaPUUba89va08U` to seperate records

Comment: `issues` is objects `0` and `1`, both containing `a` and `b`. I don't want to create the `uubaPUUba89va08U`, all I want is to add the numerical series. @PeterHaddad

Comment: The thing is it is easier to create with uubaPUUba89va08U and recommended by Firebase to use push() to seperate records. The push() is a unique key for your record. Those `0` and `1` you should not use them anyway later on, you should just use the content inside of them which is `a` and `b` and that is why push() is recommended

Answer (score 0):

Try this to be able to keep adding more nodes:

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('issues');
 var issue = ref.push();
 issues.set({
    a: 'info',
    b: 'info'
  });
}
```

Using the above, you will have this database:

```
issues
    randomid
        a: info
        b: info
    randomid
        a: info
        b: info
    randomid
        a: info
        b: info
```

The randomid is created from the `push()` method, example this in your question `-uubaPUUba89va08U`. You use the `push()` method to easily be able to seperate records like in the database above. It is better to seperate using `push()` and not numbers entered by  you like 0 or 1